# some of my elements go through my sticky footer with appendTo()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this really simple function in jquery that appendTo() a  to a specific div element. It can goes up to 20 times. And when you click on it 20 times, you have 20 little input type="file". This is okay so far but now, I have my sticky footer which is not really a sticky footer so far because my inputs are passing through it and you can see some inputs below my footer. I tried to clear:both; with css, nothing happens..What's wrong with my code?? Why is my "sticky" footer not really sticky?!

My HTML code looks like this

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="pageWrap"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS for this :

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#pageWrap {
    min-height:100%;
    margin-bottom:-136px;
}

#pageWrap:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}

#footer, #pageWrap:after {
    height: 136px;
}
```

And this is my function that actually add "too much" of inputs, which results in a list of inputs going through my footer..(This is really ugly! help!)

```
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').click(function() {
        if ( i > 20 ) {
            alert('Un maximum de 20 photos est autoriser.');
            return false;
        } else {
            $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="file" class="p_scnt" name="p_scnt_' + i +'"></label> <a href="#" class="remScnt">X</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: from where did `p_scents` came from in your jquery code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insted of declaring the height of `pageWrap` in percent first you shhould declare it in `px`. then inted of this:

```
 #pageWrap {
    min-height:100%;
    margin-bottom:-136px;
}
```

type this:

```
#pageWrap {
    min-height:800px; // you can add the height accourding to your neccessity 
    margin-bottom:-136px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

this will solve your problem

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/z6Lrd/1/)

Comment: well actually you can declare height and width in percent but for convinence declare it in px